# SQL Server - CONVERT varchar to datetime. YYYY-MM-DD 10:30:36.157 format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting the following error when trying to convert a varchar to datetime in sql server.

**The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.**

Here are the ResponseDate column values:

```
2012-06-19 10:30:36.157
2012-06-19 10:30:36.157
2012-07-09 11:37:14.287
2012-06-21 10:15:06.733
2012-07-02 13:19:13.080
```

I'm trying to write a query that selects * in july.

```
  Select * From table WHERE CONVERT(datetime,ResponseDate)  BETWEEN '20120631' AND '20120801'
```

I thought there wouldnt be any issues because the varchar is already in datetime format.

Can anyone give me advice? Thanks!

Comment: Try eliminating your `WHERE` clause and see if it still fails (move the `convert(datetime, ResponseDate)` to the `SELECT` clause so that it still executes). I suspect it's the strings in the `WHERE` clause causing the problem.

Comment: ahhh I had a dull moment. There are only 30 days in june.   WHERE  CONVERT(datetime,ResponseDate)  BETWEEN '20120630' AND '20120801' works like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following modified statement. I believe the issue is that it's trying to convert your strings in the WHERE clause to a DateTime implicitly but they aren't in a format where it can.

```
Select * From table 
WHERE 
CONVERT(datetime,ResponseDate)  BETWEEN '6/30/2012' AND '8/1/2012'
```

Comment: Thanks. The major issue, is using '6/31/2012' there are only 30 days in june, which was the cause of the error.

Comment: The minor issue is when the date is 6/30/2013 won't work on a system where mm/dd/yyyy is the default, way better off with YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - so are you saying that `YYYYMMDD` will work on absolutely **any** installation of MS SQL Server, regardless of **any** of the settings, where as `MM/DD/YYYY` won't?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson `YYYYMMDD` is always safe regardless of any settings. `YYYY-MM-DD` [is not safe for `datetime`](http://www.sommarskog.se/wishlist.html#YYYYMMDD) but is safe for the `date` in SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Haven't seen any where with sql server since 6.0 where YYYY-MM-DD doesn't work. Can't remember ever seeing a YYYY-DD-MM as a standard format anymore than YYYYDDMM. dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy are widely applicable though. If you want to be really safe use a parameterised query